# Aws lambda function with node returns "callback is not a function "

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, callback

One of my friend has this issue, we are hosting the api using lite-server, and access the api on browser, it says callback is not a function.

```
   'use strict';
    (function () {
         var StoreAPI = require('Store');
         module.exports = {            
             getBooks: function (event, context,callback) {
                 var books;
                    StoreAPI.getAll('books', function(err,data){                 
                     console.log(data);    
                     callback({
                         path: data.path, 
                         error: false, 
                         errorCode: 0, 
                         body: { 
                         books : data    
                         }           
                     });           
                 });
            }
        };
    } ());
```

url goes as:

http://localhost:3000/getBooks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue is likely caused by the code that invokes `getBooks`.

After the API call is completed, you try to call the function passed in as parameter `callback`, but as the error message says, **what you are trying to call is not a function**. To resolve this, ensure that the invoking code actually passes a function as callback.

Comment: @Sajeetharan you can't do that "in a browser url". Perhaps you need to include more information in your question about what you are doing and what you are trying to achieve.